# Magento 2 : How to add address attribute in checkout new address form?

Tags: magento2, checkout, address-attribute

I want to add some more field on checkout page new address form. For this I added some customer address attribute from script and assign that attribute in all form. But still its not coming in New address form on checkout.

Comment: you can follow this url this can be helpfull to you. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6325

Answer (score 1):

I think below link will be help to you.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_edit_form.html

Comment: we usually have gone through magento devdocs first before posting to this forum.